# how can I prevent web3 function calls printing out the Promise; I only want the actual value printed out

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

I'm using node.js to execute a simple JavaScript script that tests access to the rinkeby blockchain using an infura endpoint. specifically, it is checking the balance of my address.

In the code if I invoke:

```
console.log(web3.eth.getBalance(address));
```

it only returns the Promise i.e.

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

If on the other hand I call:

```
console.log(web3.eth.getBalance(address, function (error, result) { }));
```

it returns both the Promise and the address balance i.e..

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
18750000000000000000
```

I don't really understand why it prints out the Promise at all. I simply want it to return the value only i.e. 18750000000000000000

How can I achieve this and do I really need to specify the `function (error, result) { }` optional parameter to all the web3 function calls just to get it to return me the data I need?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with something along the lines of:

```
const get_eth_balance = async (web3, account) => {

  const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(account);

  return balance;
};

get_eth_balance(web3, account);
```

The main keywords here being the [async/await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) which make the code look much saner than it would by using callbacks.

Comment: firstly, thank you for your prompt and informative response:

your code only serves to print out: 

"getting account balance: [object Promise]"

not the actual value I'm expecting. Am I missing something else here?

Also, does the async/wait approach mean I can dispense with the much more verbose and hard-to-read Promise.then() syntax?

Comment: yes, you can also use it like `web3.eth.getBalance(account).then( balance => {console.log(balance)} )`

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly the current web3 version (v1.0) doesn't support synchronous operations. If you want synchronous functions (without promises or async/await) you could install the previous version by doing the following:

`npm install web3@0.20`

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io'))
const address = '0x966e42aA4E7368818517a93656362C30d8E4d5fE'
const balance = web3.eth.getBalance(address)
console.log(balance.toNumber())
```